# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's the time of the year again, namely it is December 2013, and so we shall now refresh our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for physics research
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5263).

Comment: Is Community Promotion Ads still on? Can I use it if I have a science-y Area51 propodal to promote?

Comment: Yes, they're still active, and will still be active until December when the next thread goes up. You can propose an ad for a proposal but I'm not the person who you'll need the approval of - it'll be your peers who will decide by voting whether or not they'll have the ad fly.

Answer (score 51):

[image: arXiv.org -- open access to over 800 000 e-prints]

Answer (score 42):

[image: Detexify2 - LaTeX symbol classifier]

Answer (score 38):

[image: MIT's Open Courseware]

Answer (score 31):

[image: Community Promotion Ads are proposed and voted on by the Physics SE community]

Comment: Great idea.  Not enough folks know about this.  I was really surprised when I learned about it months ago.

Comment: @Brandon for the record, I'm dead sure this isn't an original idea. I've seen this *somewhere* in the community ads of some other site of some unspecifiable year, but I can't quite place it at the moment. The design, on the other hand, is original and fresh out the oven.

Comment: (with a huge load of physics.se overall design thrown in, of course.)

Answer (score 26):

[Browse through our unanswered questions! http://mma-se-ads.herokuapp.com/static/physics/unanswered.png](https://physics.stackexchange.com/unanswered)

Comment: **Huge** thanks to [rm -rf](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rf), from Mathematica.SE, for building [the MM.SE version of this dynamic ad](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1168), and porting it for Physics. Image is a retina display (440x500px) and [should work fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214846/).

Answer (score 22):

[image: Chemistry Stack Exchange]

Comment: “Nuclei and electrons ⇒ chemistry” is a blatant overgeneralization. There are some question involving atomic orbitals (such as magnetic moment of an atom) that are exclusively physical. I also can point to [a physical question about π bond](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104679/why-is-the-orbital-angular-momentum-of-a-pi-electron-along-the-axis-of-two-atoms).

Comment: @IncnisMrsi of course, this wasn't meant to be an exhaustive ad. And SE sites can have scope overlap.

Answer (score 22):

[image: Digital Library of Mathematical Functions]

Comment: [Inkscape source (SVG)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/DLMF%20ad.svg).

Answer (score 22):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Comment: Originally posted by Tildalwave. I thought this might be an attractive one ;-)

Answer (score 21):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 20):

[Current Physics Stack Exchange bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/physics.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://physics.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: Works perfectly (even if the size looks big).

Comment: The size is important. The images are 'reaped' automatically by the system, and images with the wrong size will be rejected. Nice one, though!

Comment: Dear @EmilioPisanty , 

Check  the Apple.SE site where it works pretty fine: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @all: The size appears to be higher than 220x240 but it is perfectly displayed, just see the Apple.SE site.

Comment: Fair enough, yeah. Let's go for it, I say.

Comment: Well, it seems like our [skeptic fellas](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/2586) also use the bounty counter :)

Comment: This is nice, but it's a little funny when it says there are no bounties. Maybe it can be customised to only display when there are at least a few bounties, say 100 rep or more, or `150.

Comment: @GraceNote, is dimension10's idea feasible?

Comment: @Emilio We can't configure the ads system on our end to display based on bounty status - this is a user-made widget so making special effects for empty bounty status is up to the creators to design.

Answer (score 19):

[image: Try Sage open-source mathematical software system]

Answer (score 18):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 18):

[image: arXiv.org: the biggest open-access e-print repository for maths and physics]

Comment: I know we already have one arXiv ad - to which I just proposed a modification - but I'd still like to propose this. The arXiv does not normally push for researchers to upload, but I think this is innocuous enough. It is actually primarily aimed at non-researchers, to help bring home the message that the arXiv does have a huge chunk of the world's physics papers in it.

Comment: Source is a Fireworks PNG so it's actually an editable vector image if you can get at the proprietary vector layers. (Same for the other one.)

Comment: Slightly better-looking version [here](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1504/820).

Answer (score 16):

[image: writeLaTeX.com - great for explaining physics, and works on your iPad too!]

Answer (score 16):

[image: Astronomy Stack Exchange]

Comment: Image Credit: [@TildalWave](http://meta.astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/177/6)

Answer (score 15):

[image: Khan|Academy]

Answer (score 15):

[image: LaTeX Search]

Comment: Online tool for searching equations and their LaTeX code, so that you don't need to re-create them!

Comment: [Twenty-four results for `\gamma^5`?](http://www.latexsearch.com/latexFacets.do?searchInput=%5Cgamma%5E5&stype=exact)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty And 700 for `\gamma^2` and 100 for `x^5`. Well, it looked really promissing when I came across it. Still, people can find it useful I think.

Comment: Yes, but \gamma^5 is [\gamma^5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#The_fifth_gamma_matrix.2C_.CE.B35).

Answer (score 14):

[image: A beautiful, free online graphing calculator]

Comment: Originally posted [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11920/community-promotion-ads-2014/12168#12168).

Comment: Too bad the superimposed text on this ad is not beautiful.

Answer (score 14):

[image: PhysicsOverflow: a graduate-level upward physics site]

Comment: It was obvious to have down votes :-(. Nonetheless '+1'

Comment: +1 From me too! It is a great website, and I hope there can be some mutual friendliness between the two sites. I don't really understand the "[you're either with us, or against us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You're_either_with_us,_or_against_us)" mentality some people seem to adapt.

Comment: @Hunter personally, I can't support a site that has no expectation of civility. Just be sure you're not seeing that mentality where there is actually something more going on.

Comment: @Hunter for those who are interested, [here](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1608/30967) and [here](http://motls.blogspot.de/2014/05/physics-overflow-is-live.html?m=0) are two short comments explaining a bit more accurately than what David Z said what PhysicsOverflow is meant to be.

Comment: To add some transparency to the downvotes, I am one of them. I have indicated a willingness to discuss this in an appropriate space on this site (i.e. chat) but the Physics Overflow organizers did not really respond.

Comment: I must say that I feel they responded very badly to [the accusations of phishing on this thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5697/) (some comments now deleted). I am also not happy that, for a site that would like to be considered as a professional forum, their [users list](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/users) shows me as an active user and therefore makes it look as though I endorse it regardless of whether I do or not. (I also wonder what e.g. Gil Kalai thinks about that.) It is not clear from the outside what the formal moderation is but there are a few big red lights for me.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty thanks for catching the typo. Personally, I was rather appaled about the moderators reluctance (it took them about a week to delete the very inappropriate meta post) in dealing appropriately with the throwing around of very bad (including statements about criminal intentions) accusations of a particular user in the course of the "Phishing Affair". Happily this bad episode is now over...  If you read the user profiles you can clearly see who is active and who is not, and when looking at the posts and comments you can discern the imported ones by the attribution line. Peace now...

Comment: To be clear, I do not think you addressed the serious and valid concerns on phishing in any meaningful or positive way. And unless you gray out the inactive users' profiles in a visible way *on* the users page, I will continue to not thank you for using my name without my consent. Ultimately, though, it is up to you - just don't stand and wonder why there's a lack of support from this community.

Comment: @DavidZ Most of the users just want a good site where they can ask questions and get answers; PhysicsOverflow is just another one, and we should appreciate their effort. ِSome users had problems with them when they were trying to change the atmosphere of this site. But now they're gone and have built **another** site. I really can't see what's your problem **now** !

Comment: @Mostafa no, just because Physics Overflow exists doesn't _automatically_ mean we should appreciate the effort put in to make it. I've already said why I don't consider this particular site to be a good use of our ad space.

Comment: I am indifferent to “civility wars” that happened here long before me, but this splinter group is dysfunctional as a community. They do not want to think, they only try to rise their self-esteem by mutual admiration. A doomed site IMHO.

Comment: Related meta question: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6196/2451

Answer (score 13):

[image: Free online collaborative $\LaTeX$ editor]

Comment: Edited with a much better version.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Zotero reference manager: free and open source]

Answer (score 11):

[image: The Fun Physics]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Image is a Fireworks vector PNG.

Comment: ... and many thanks to @Manishearth for writing and maintaining this script.

Comment: The newer versions of Google Chrome disable this extension since it is not available from the Chrome Store. Would you please submit the extension to the Chrome Store for distribution.

Comment: You need to ping @Manishearth about that. For this and other issues with the script, the ideal place is the stack apps page.

Answer (score 9):

[image: SciRate]

Comment: Source: https://gist.github.com/stared/017c8af055f79aa7480f

Comment: Piotr, I forked that one over into https://gist.github.com/episanty/f997037226c468bb44ec to up it to the 2016 specs. Feel free to merge back in or whatever.

Answer (score 6):

[image: arXiv Analytics: specialized web portal dedicated to reading & discussing arXiv eprints]

Comment: I don't like the word "Another" at all. It implies that there's already a good one, and why should I bother with this one instead of going to the original?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks a lot for your comments. Any suggestions for a better phrase?

Comment: I'm trying to get a sense for what the website does, but I can't find any reviews. Is that part of the system running yet?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Yes, it is running. Have an example at http://arxitics.com/reviews/1 The website is still under construction and there are only a few users.

Comment: How about `Read, explore, review and discuss preprints and papers`?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Registered users can subscribe, bookmark, review eprints. This part is almost complete. The reviews section can also used to discuss eprints. Currently, we are working on the exploring functionalities.

Comment: I find it a bit hard to navigate the site - I'm never sure whether the section is running or whether I've messed up. (e.g. `Explore → Reviews tab → Active tab` produces an empty page - presumably not quite the desired behaviour?) Do you have a log with a description of what's running and what's not? That would be nice to have while there are still large parts under construction.

Comment: (The proposal was a possible advert phrase. I don't think you should shoot for an exhaustive list of your (future?) capabilities on adverts.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty A good start may be the help center: http://arxitics.com/help

Comment: We did not hide any unfinished features so that users can have an idea of our plan and send us comments or suggestions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18046/discussion-between-emilio-pisanty-and-soliton).

Answer (score 6):

[image: For the geeks interested in fun science questions and answers.]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Astrobites]

Answer (score 5):

[image: robotics stack exchange]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. Last year this actually was deleted, huh.

Comment: Well, I think it's okay here. Physics.SE is doing very well on twitter :)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy A number of people have been quite disappointed with the behavior of the site-specific Twitter feeds (like this one). They seem to more or less randomly choose questions to tweet and thus a lot of relatively bad content winds up getting shared. (But of course you can make your own judgment about this)

Comment: @DavidZ: I get your point. Questions under bounties and *Can you answer this?* stuff (in twitter) can sometimes be bad. But, others are quite okay (probably highly voted stuff) :D

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: This is a good idea but it would be nice to have a more descriptive ad.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty How should I make it more descriptive?

Comment: Well, try something that is not just a logo and which says what the target is and why it is relevant here.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I am not finding a good image. How about [this](http://pad1.whstatic.com/images/thumb/3/3d/Use-the-Internet-Archive's-Wayback-Machine-Step-1.jpg/400px-Use-the-Internet-Archive's-Wayback-Machine-Step-1.jpg).

Comment: If anyone knows about archive.org site please edit a good picture in my post.

Comment: The new image is even worse and it does not comply with the size requirements. Think about why you think this is relevant and build on that. If you provide a good mock-up made e.g. in MS Paint, I *may* have time to make a pretty version. Have a look at the other ads: they all say pretty much right away why you should click on them with the possible exception of the two space.se ads, which are graphically strong enough to stand on their own.

Comment: Related: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/911/820

Comment: I changed the picture to that from http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1045/49. I hope now it looks nicer. For tweaks or anything, the source is here: https://gist.github.com/stared/a9538e926e05f0a5b157.

Comment: Even the active websites used to go there. Google is a perfect example.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Magma Computational Algebra System]

Comment: '-1' The image is not descriptive.

Comment: +1 for [obvious reason](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6967/19341)...

Comment: @draks... It looks like nice software but I'm afraid that the use cases for physicists are rather limited, which explains the relatively lukewarm reaction.

Answer (score 1):

[image: WorldCat - the online catalogue of the world's libraries, online]

Comment: [Inkscape source (SVG)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/WorldCat%20ad.svg).

Comment: The "The world's..." appears to me in greek in the SVG source.

Comment: That's quite curious. It shows in latin on my computer (Ubuntu) but the font name is indeed 'Symbol'. Just change the font for something similar - or whatever looks good, really.

Answer (score 1):

[image: THE NET ADVANCE OF PHYSICS]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Find perfect Explanations at PerfectExplanations.com]

Answer (score 0):

[image: This Week in Science – The Kickass Science Podcast]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Physics Forums]

Comment: We have several smaller "competing" science sites in the list so it seemed kind of silly to omit Physics Forums. (The image was kindly contributed by PF's founder and lead admin, Greg.) I'm posting this here so we remember to add it to next year's community ad thread.

Comment: I tend to find Physics Forums, while well-intentioned, to be the complete opposite of the "get your answer without dissecting a 5-page message thread" approach of this site.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty indeed; in fact it's right in the name: Physics _Forums_. But of course, if one were to apply that logic to say that PF shouldn't appear here, it would also disqualify some sites that we already _do_ advertise - and generally speaking, I don't think there's any argument against showing this ad that wouldn't also take out several others in the same way.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any particular reason not to advertise it. I just haven't found it helpful yet. (Just sayin', is what I'm saying.)

Answer (score -2):

[image: Internet Archive]

Comment: The image is taken from [Piotr Migdal's post on ACADEMIA](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/980/13359).

Comment: This is essentially an exact duplicate of [this answer](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/5733/3) and I don't see what re-posting it adds to the discussion. The [current ad on that answer](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5733) is a lot closer to the descriptiveness that these ads need; its only problem is it's ugly. As I said before I can put in some graphic design work as it's a good place to link to, but you need to provide some input yourself, and repeating stuff you posted already is hardly the way to get people's attention. -1.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty The 7 upvotes on Piotr's answer shows that the name itself is self explanatory. Technically this answer is **not** an exact duplicate of my previous answer's previous version; this is of appropriate size. This answer is downvoted only because it is posted by me.

Comment: Please do not attribute intentions behind other people's actions. A focus on how you can improve your posts instead of how you perceive the community to be against you will do wonders in getting people to help you instead of downvote your posts.

Answer (score -2):

[image: Qiqqa: Essential software for PDF and research management]

Comment: I'm curious as to why this was downvoted. I haven't used Qiqqa yet as they don't have a linux version (yet) but it looks very solid from the outside. Is it simply the (admittedly deficient) graphic design?

Comment: (In which case - Qiqqa don't seem to provide the same level of workable brand materials as e.g. [zotero](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5263/community-promotion-ads-2014/) does.)

Answer (score -3):

[image: iphooichoo]

Comment: I'm afraid that it couldn't be displayed properly because of the size.

Answer (score -4):

[image: robotics stack exchange]

Comment: Terrible font..

Comment: @Adobe - The font was a deliberate stylistic choice, intended to evoke golden age of robotics in science fiction. In many ways it would be better if it hadn't been anti-aliased at all, if I find the time I'll try to work out if I can make the text crisper.

Comment: @MarkBooth if you're trying to invoke the golden age you should really use the [original](http://static1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110305210118/hitchhikers/images/b/b8/Marvin_meets_Ford_and_Arthur.jpg) Marvin!

Comment: Sadly I couldn't find any unencumbered MtPA artwork to use @Nathaniel otherwise I would have used that.