# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for physics research
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/9554).

Comment: @peterh ?${}{}$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Sorry something happened badly, I wanted to close as dupe of the [2018 community ads](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10394/32426)...

Comment: @peterh yeah, that's what it looked like :-P

Answer (score 21):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Comment: For mostly text (as opposed to math symbols), see also [Optical Character Recognition (OCR) software online](https://www.onlineocr.net/).

Answer (score 18):

[image: Physics Stack Exchange Review Queue]

Comment: From the [2016 Com. Promo. Ads](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/7449/25301)

Comment: Only if I had time to make a spinoff of this for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) whose review queues are constantly crushed under 3-digit backlogs...

Comment: @dorukayhan our was straight forward enough to make: just save the image from the top bar & then add in some color and text. Definitely worth it, methinks.

Answer (score 17):

[image: arXiv.org: the leading open access eprint repository]

Comment: If folks want to shake up the tagline I'm happy to implement suggestions.

Answer (score 16):

[image: Digital Open Access Identifier - a DOI resolver that prioritizes open access]

Comment: Soliciting comments: should this be changed to [oaDOI](https://oadoi.org/)?

Comment: yes it should imho

Answer (score 15):

[image: Community ads are run by the community. Come and vote!]

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Do you mind if I post a similar ad for chemistry SE(I will mention your name in comments)?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Please go ahead - no need to attribute unless you use the graphic or a very close adaptation. As I mentioned in [the original iteration](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5571), the idea is not mine but I can't place where I got it from. That said, if you want to attribute it, it's welcome.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Retraction Watch]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Wayback Machine: experience the Web as it was]

Answer (score 13):

[image: chemistry.stackexchange.com]

Comment: From the [2016 Community Promotion Ads](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/7468/121464) thread. Made by [Martin - マーチン](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/users/104362/martin-%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%81%E3%83%B3).

Answer (score 12):

[image: History of Science and Mathematics at Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 11):

[image: The Cost of Knowledge - join the Elsevier boycott and take back our scientific publishing!]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Sage Mathematical Software Environment]

Comment: From the [2016 Comm. Promo thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/9053/25301)

Answer (score 11):

[image: tex.stackexchange]

Comment: From [2016 Math.SE Community Promotion Ads](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22422/352306). Made by Alenanno.

Comment: According to ISO, the e, i, and π shall be upright and not italic.

Comment: @Loong ... and plenty of other style guides (including e.g. the Phys. Rev. guide) say that it should be italic. Put another way: this is a subjective issue and the current image is a valid viewpoint. Deal with it.

Comment: That said, the maths looks a bit blurry to me, and the whole ad could use a bit of sharpening up.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, really? the ad appears quite crisp to me.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Discover our universe]

Comment: From the [2016 Comm. Promo thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/7515/25301)

Answer (score 9):

[image: The Physics Travel Guide]

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks for the feedback! I've removed it and updated the image with a better description

Answer (score 8):

[image: www.physicsoverflow.org]

Comment: Due to prior experience, we're asking everyone to avoid discussion in the comment section here. Instead, use the [related meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6196/2451) and [its chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17799).

Answer (score 8):

[image: DLMF: an online encyclopaedia of special functions]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Computational Science at Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Engineering Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 7):

[image: archive.org - the public library of the internet]

Comment: I will shamelessly steal that for [Chemistry.se](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3581/4945).

Answer (score 6):

[image: Overleaf: Free online collaborative LaTeX editor with real-time PDF preview]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Are your papers available in an open access repository? Check with Dissemin]

Answer (score 4):

[image: cryptography.stackexchange.com]

Comment: From the [2016 Community Promotion Ads thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7426/community-promotion-ads-2016/7449#7449). Made by [e-sushi](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/users/8031/e-sushi) and then brought to the 2016 thread by [The Dark Side](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/46399/the-dark-side).

Answer (score 3):

[image: You can also join us in the CS room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59701/join-cs-educators]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Zotero reference manager: free and open source]

Answer (score 2):

[image: space.stackexchange.com]

Comment: Thanks to Emilio Pisanty, ACuriousMind, obe, anonymous, John Rennie, Kyle Kanos, and others in the hbar for ideas and criticism.

Comment: tagline text looks pretty blurry in this version for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

[image: SciRate]

Answer (score 0):

[image: math.stackexchange.com]

Comment: Thanks to [anonymous](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35231480#35231480) for the tag line idea.

Comment: MSE is [plenty big already](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), and plenty well known. I don't really see the case for using our ad space to send them even more traffic.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, people here use math.se. I think it's worth an ad.

Comment: People here also use Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Internet Explorer, but that doesn't mean that we should use our ad space for that. This space is for things that are useful to the community but not well-known enough. MSE is the former but not the latter.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Physics Forums]

Comment: Adapted [from the 2015 ad thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6397/124)

Answer (score -4):

[image: March supporting government policy informed by science]

Comment: I know something almost the same has already been submitted, and downvoted, but i wondered if that maybe had to do with having added to the original format used by the campaign.

Comment: If you see this as political (which i think is debatable),  and don't think it belongs here, it has been proposed also for Academia.SE, where it falls within the site's mandate much more clearly. If you are a member there, that post is [here](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/3692/69922).

Comment: I don't think it's political nature is the issue I have with it, but the transient nature. It is going to come and pass, but this ad will still linger if it reached threshold (at this rate, it won't though).

Comment: @KyleKanos Ads remain connected to this Meta post, so they can be removed from rotation by deleting the answer, or if the vote count falls below 6.

Comment: in principle, that is true. In practice, that's not always happened. I still feel that transient events can be acknowledged in other ways than an ad

Comment: @KyleKanos That feels like a red herring to me. The ad just gets deleted after the march and that's it. Set a reminder on your calendar to flag it for moderator deletion if it really bothers you.

Answer (score -7):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Comment: And so the downvoting begins...

Comment: @heather yeah, there's a longstanding tradition of dissatisfaction with the algorithm that chooses which questions to tweet.