# Community Promotion Ads - 2018

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's almost February in 2018, which isn't supposed to be the proper time to cycle these, but for this year it'll be once again, so we'll be refreshing the **Community Promotion Ads** for this year now!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for physics research
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/10394).

Answer (score 16):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Answer (score 16):

[image: archive.org - the public library of the internet]

Answer (score 13):

[image: arXiv.org: the leading open access eprint repository]

Comment: Boy, the arXiv ad sure has [seen better days](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5266/8563). Though then again the vote totals are generally lower these days.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Community ads are run by the community. Come and vote!]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Quantum Computing Stack Exchange]

Comment: The logo font looks *close* to Proxima Nova but it isn't quite that, either. It doesn't fully get the `t`, but it does a rather better job with the `Q`.

Comment: I [asked on qc.meta](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/77/176) to see if they'll make one. I'm not keeping any hopes up but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - This is where we seem to be discussing this: https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/112/278 .

Comment: @Daniel whatcha think of [this](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/198/176) as an alternative?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I like it but I wouldn't change the community and unless the site's logo changes.

Comment: @DanielSank a'ight =). I've made some minor edits here to tidy it up (particularly, bringing the logo font and the background to the site's standard). The Inkscape source svg is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztko5re11fi5f6b/quantum-computing-2018-2.svg?dl=0) if you want to tinker with it.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I like the new font and colors, but I liked the arrangement of the other one better. No big deal, obviously.

Answer (score 9):

[image: History of Science and Mathematics at Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 9):

[image: DLMF: an online encyclopaedia of special functions]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: The font looks better, but curious what the moon is supposed to be orbiting now?

Comment: @KyleKanos I don't think it matters too much, it's aesthetic. Quick question, do you think [making the A a tripod](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wSQLF.png) would be too much?

Comment: I think it looks fine either way. It isn't too much to have it, but I don't think it's missing anything were you to leave it as-is.

Comment: @SirCumference Didn't you make the image click-able? For example if I click on the other community ads, the link opens.

Comment: @KyleKanos Well, presumably it's orbiting a Lagrange point, I should imagine.

Comment: @KyleKanos It’s because astronomy is their world. . . .

Comment: @SirCumference the [2021 thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13630/community-ads-for-2021) is now open; it'd be good to have this one there as well.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Computational Science at Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 8):

[image: SciRate]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Physics Stack Exchange Review Queue]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Retraction Watch]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Wayback Machine: experience the Web as it was]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Comment: The font here is much smaller than it ought to - the double-sized version reads fine, but the displayed ad has a tiny font size which will be very hard to read, particularly for older users and others with even mild visual impairment. Considering how much whitespace this has, this ought to be changed.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I changed it. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: That's definitely better. The lines look all askew to me, but that's just personal taste.

Comment: This thread is now superseded [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11001/community-promotion-ads-2019); you may want to re-post there.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Are your papers available in an open access repository? Check with Dissemin]

Answer (score 4):

[image: The Cost of Knowledge - join the Elsevier boycott and take back our scientific publishing!]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Engineering Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 3):

[image: A powerful graphing tool]

Answer (score 2):

[image: PhysicsOverflow]

Comment: Due to prior experience, we're asking everyone to avoid discussion in the comment section here. Instead, use the [related meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6196/2451) and [its chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17799).

Answer (score 2):

[image: Haikus are awesome/ Chemistry is more so/ Ask straight away!]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Zotero reference manager: free and open source]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Physics Forums]

Comment: Copied from [the 2017 ad thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9657/124)

Answer (score -4):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting