# Are there any advanced undergraduate study chat rooms on Physics Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, chat

Edit: per rob's comment, I've started a Physics Chat room for this purpose here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137879/binomials!
I am an undergraduate physics major.

To clarify, I am not referring to a study group for doing homework. I am envisioning a study group for the sake of learning.

Is there a group of interested and motivated students who frequently discuss physics associated with Physics Stack Exchange? If not, would anyone like to start one with me?

I am thinking about a group of students (beyond introductory physics) who self-study or learn via other methods who would benefit from discussing questions or concepts more fluidly, i.e., in conversations or chats. For example, someone I talk to frequently is self-studying Quantum Mechanics from Griffiths over the summer and we discuss problems and concepts from that book (@relativisticcucumber). Likewise, I am working through some sections of Jackson E&M and discuss with her.

I feel like I miss out on the opportunity to work with other interested students due to the nature of my university's size and emphasis (on not physics). It seems Physics Stack Exchange would have a greater concentration of the described students.

Comment: A good place for this kind of thing is [chat]. If you develop a small group and you'd like to cultivate more people, you can consider setting up a "chat event," whose details are documented ... somewhere.

Comment: There is a pretty big Physics server on Discord that appeals to the said demographic. You can take a look at it here: https://discord.com/invite/physics

Comment: Just for the record, I created the room [Find Your Physics Partner](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113061/find-your-physics-partner) to help link people interested in physics study/research groups, and advertised it [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13634/226060). However, the suggestion was *heavily* downvoted (!?); now this similar suggestion has been heavily upvoted. (*I wonder whether I can hope that posts, **not** their posters, are judged here and other meta sites (and also other human communities).*)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's worth a try, and I see you've now created a chat room for the purpose. The problem is finding enough like minded site members to keep the room active. Over the eleven years I've been a site member I've seen this attempted many times and it rarely works out. So don't be too disappointed if it's not a success.

If you have specific questions about physics then asking them in [the h Bar chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) is always worth a shot. We have a broad range of physicists hanging out there and there's likely to be someone who can help.